# Best Practice of Maintaining an Object Repository when web page renamed

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

I inherited a QTP/UFT script for a web page that has not been used in a long time and I want to get it running again. My challenge is because the page has been renamed, whenever I use the record button, it creates a new Repository object against the new name, not the old name.

For example.
The current repository is called:

```
Browser("Web Page").Page("Web Page")
```

But the web page name has been slightly changed since this was previously run so recording anything new is storing everything in.

```
Browser("Web Page Suite").Page("Web Page Suite")
```

Now I have to manually drag and drop everything into the old test object name so this one new statement will look like the other code, or rename the repository to the new web page name, then slightly rename the rest

I was wondering what is the best practice for maintaining an object repository for writing decoupled code that can be reused rather than for the current point in time?